# What does it mean to make a jar OSGi bundle

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I am using a lib that has the following in the POM:

```
<!-- Plus, let's make jars OSGi bundles as well  -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
          <configuration>
            <instructions>
              <Bundle-Name>${project.name}</Bundle-Name>
              <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
              <Bundle-Description>${project.description}</Bundle-Description>
              <Import-Package>
javax.xml.namespace, javax.xml.parsers, javax.xml.stream, javax.xml.stream.util,
javax.xml.transform, javax.xml.transform.dom, javax.xml.transform.sax, javax.xml.transform.stream,
org.codehaus.stax2, org.codehaus.stax2.io, org.codehaus.stax2.ri, org.codehaus.stax2.typed,
org.codehaus.stax2.validation,
org.codehaus.stax2.ri.dom, org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt, org.codehaus.stax2.ri.typed,
org.w3c.dom,
org.xml.sax, org.xml.sax.ext, org.xml.sax.helpers
</Import-Package>
              <DynamicImport-Package>
</DynamicImport-Package>
              <Private-Package>
</Private-Package>
              <Export-Package>
com.fasterxml.aalto*
</Export-Package>
            </instructions>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I wonder what is the implication for the application using it?

What does it mean to be OSGi bundle?

It is an xml library faster xml aalto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jar being an OSGI bundle means it is ready to be used in OSGI containers. a jar with the bundle information in the manifest file becomes an OSGI bundle. The pom plugin above will generate the meta information that specifies what packages in this jar are exported and what are imported and much more. An OSGI bundle can be generated from a jar using offline tool such as bnd.

Comment: Can an OSGI application have multiple class path ?